# How can I show that the Ruby `for` loop is in fact implemented using the `each` method?

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop, each

In the book ***Eloquent Ruby (page 21, first edition, sixth printing)***, the author (Russ Olsen) advocates using the `each` method instead of the `for` loop and this is in line with everything I've read elsewhere.

However the author also goes on to say that one reason to do so is that the `for` loop does in fact call the `each` method, so why not just cut out the middle-man and use `each`? So I was wondering how this actually works.

To investigate I did do a search on the Ruby repo on github, but was finding it difficult to pinpoint where/how I could see this in action.

To restate the question:

**How can I show the Ruby `for` loop is in fact implemented using the `each` method?**

Comment: You could look at the [ruby source code on github](https://github.com/ruby/ruby), although it's a little hard to search for `for`.

Comment: I didn't find the right place in the source code yet. But here's a [snippet of official documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/syntax/control_expressions.rdoc#for-loop) that confirms that `for` calls `each`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can show it by writing a class that implements each:

```
# Demo that for calls each

class ThreeOf
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def each(&block)
    puts "In Each"
    block.call(@value)
    block.call(@value)
    block.call(@value)
  end
end
```

And then make an instance and use it in a for loop:

```
collection = ThreeOf.new(99)

for i in collection
  puts i
end
```

Run that and you will see the message printed out and the for "loop" will go round three times.

Alternatively (and more fun) you can monkey patch the built in Array class:

```
class Array
  alias_method :orig_each, :each

  def each(*args, &block)
    puts "Array Each called!"
    orig_each(*args, &block)
  end
end

puts "For loop with array"
for i in [1,2,3]
  puts i
end
```

And again you will see the message printed.

Comment: Since Ruby 2.0.0, you can also prepend a module to `Array` instead of aliasing its `each`.

Comment: Very very clever and yet so simple. Thanks for taking the time to answer Russ, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of the `for` expression are defined in the [ISO Ruby Language Specification](http://iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579) like this:

> ## §11.4.1.2.3 The `for` expression
>
> ### Syntax
>
> - *for-expression* **→** <kbd>for</kbd> *for-variable* <kbd>in</kbd> *expression*  *do-clause* <kbd>end</kbd>
> - *for-variable* **→** *left-hand-side* **|** *multiple-left-hand-side*
>
> The *expression* of a *for-expression* shall not be a *jump-expression*.
>
> ### Semantics
>
> A *for-expression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate the *expression*. Let `O` be the resulting value.
> 2. Let `E` be the *primary-method-invocation* of the form *primary-expression* **[no line-terminator here]**<kbd>.each do |</kbd> *block-formal-argument-list* <kbd>|</kbd> *block-body* <kbd>end</kbd>, where the value of the *primary-expression* is `O`,the *block-formal-argument-list* is the *for-variable*, the *block-body* is the *compound-statement* of the *do-clause*.
>
>    Evaluate `E`, but skip Step c of §11.2.2.
> 3. The value of the *for-expression* is the resulting value of the invocation.

Okay, so basically this means that

```
for for_variable in expression
  do_clause
end
```

is evaluated the same as

```
O = expression
O.each do |for_variable|
  do_clause
end
```

Aha! But we forgot something! There's this ominous "skip Step c of §11.2.2." thing! So, what does Step c of §11.2.2. say?

> - Push an empty set of local variable bindings onto ⟦local-variable-bindings⟧.

Note that Step b

> - Set the execution context to `E`<sub>`b`</sub>.

is *not* skipped.

So, a `for` loop gets its own execution context, which starts out as a copy of the current execution context, but it *does not* get its own set of local variable bindings. IOW: it gets its own dynamic execution context, but not its own lexical scope.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I show the Ruby for loop is in fact implemented using the each method?

Look at the bytecode.

```
ruby --dump insns -e 'for n in 1..10; puts n; end'
```

Which prints

```
== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<compiled>@<compiled>>==========
== catch table
| catch type: break  st: 0002 ed: 0006 sp: 0000 cont: 0006
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
local table (size: 2, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1, kw: -1@-1, kwrest: -1])
[ 2] n          
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 putobject        1..0
0004 send             <callinfo!mid:each, argc:0, block:block in <compiled>>
0006 leave            
== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:block in <compiled>@<compiled>>=
== catch table
| catch type: redo   st: 0006 ed: 0013 sp: 0000 cont: 0006
| catch type: next   st: 0006 ed: 0013 sp: 0000 cont: 0013
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
local table (size: 2, argc: 1 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1, kw: -1@-1, kwrest: -1])
[ 2] ?<Arg>     
0000 getlocal_OP__WC__0 2                                             (   1)
0002 setlocal_OP__WC__1 2
0004 trace            256
0006 trace            1
0008 putself          
0009 getlocal_OP__WC__1 2
0011 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:puts, argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>
0013 trace            512
0015 leave
```

As you can see it calls `each` with a block on the first `0004` line.